# File content is served instead of running the published app

Tags: google-app-engine

I have the following yaml:

```
runtime:   python27
api_version: 1 
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

In the main.py I have a wsgi serving "Hello world" for the route "/(.*)".

Now the issue I have is that when I execute:

```
curl -v -H 'Host: myapp.appspot.com' 'https://storage.googleapis.com/greetme'
```

Even though I can see that the SNI and Host is the expected, I get:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to myapp.appspot.com/test.</Details></Error>
```

But if I use postman or fiddler for the same request then I get the actual "Hello World"

I have tried to debug this, by looking the exact headers sent in each case but with no luck. Even after sending exactly identical headers I got the same issue.

This think is driving me crazy any ideas why I have this behaviour?

EDIT:
It looks like when I use the proxy, main.py is serving my request
but when I use the curl, then the server is trying to locate e.g. in the given example the greetme resource on myapp.appspot.com completely bypassing my pythonapplicaton. I have tried btw to change the user-agent but nothing. Still not sure why this is happening.

**EDIT2:**
After taking a look at wireshark, fiddler is opening two ssl connections, the first at storage.googleapis.com and the second at myapp.appspot.net. So the connection at myapp.appspot.net is not routed through the first session.

So it works as expected for curl and fiddler (but not as I would like).
Regardless of that, if I create a file test.txt on my bucket and provide the read permission to allusers then the:

```
curl -v -H 'Host: myapp.appspot.com' 'https://storage.googleapis.com/test.txt'
```

**Returns the actual content of my test.txt and is routed through googleapis. Shouldn't there be a way of running my application as well? or they allow domain fronting only for static content?**

Comment: I think curl's `-H` only adds an HTTP header (see doc: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H).  SNI is part of the TLS/SSL handshake which is done before HTTP headers are examined.  In fact, HTTP(S) is not the only protocol that uses TLS/SSL, so SNI must be independent of HTTP(S) and its headers.

Comment: BTW, just do `curl -v 'https://myapp.appspot.com/greetme'`

Comment: @BareNakedCoder the headers are exactly identical to what fiddler/postman are sending. sni=storage.googleapis.com Host=myapp.appspot.com and this is what I want.

Comment: Okay, wishing you luck.  I'd be curious to know if you get this working.  Sending a request to Google Cloud Storage (storage.googleapis.com) and getting a response from Google App Engine (cname ghs.googlehosted.com) would be something.

Comment: it's called domain fronting